# Illustrator 19 can't change polygon (or any path) appearence under 4pt stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, mac, windows, cc-2019

[image]

I can't change the appearance of the stroke on this polygon to anything under 4pt stroke, and I can't change the corners from anything but round joint. Turning off the stroke does nothing, and only change the stroke size above 4pt changes the appearance. Even then I can only change the stroke weight, nothing else.

When I create a new polygon, it's fine, until I save the file and load it up again.

File was created on a 2018 version of AI on a MAC. File has been edited on 2018 and 2019 versions of AI on a PC as well.

I am a student, so switching between versions and PC/MAC is mandatory because I have to work in class and at home.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The **Layer itself** has an Appearance applied to it.

[image]

You may have a stroke applied to the *layer* which makes everything on that layer appear to have the same stroke.

Highlight the layer in the Layers Panel and then check the **Appearance Panel** for additional strokes there.

Answer (score 0):

You may also have applied a style to a whole layer or group, which casuses inabilities in changing stroke or fill in a similiar fashion to the one you mention.